# Construct MulipartFormDataInput request for REST API?

Tags: spring, rest, http, multipartform-data, resteasy

I have a REST API with the following signature:

```
@POST
@Path("/bulkControlsMapping")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
Response saveControlsMapping(@NonNull MultipartFormDataInput input);
```

and in my API I'm extracting my data from the input as:

```
Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
// For text
InputPart inputPart = uploadForm.get(TEXT_KEY).get(0);

// For file
InputPart inputPart = uploadForm.get(CONTROLS_FILE_KEY).get(0);
```

I'm calling this REST API from Spring MVC web service, where I'm constructing my request as:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MultipartWriter.class);
String endPoint = "https://localhost:8080/";
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(endPoint).path("bulkControlsMapping");


MultipartFormDataOutput multipartFormDataOutput = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData(CONTROLS_FILE_KEY,
                file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
multipartFormDataOutput.addFormData(TEXT_KEY, countryCode, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);


Response response = webTarget.request()
                .post(Entity.entity(multipartFormDataOutput, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
```

But I'm getting 400 bad Request Exception in this due to no Content-Disposition header found within the part. What is the correct way to build this request?

```
     [java] 03 Sep 2017 21:16:56,300 [WARN]  (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-12) org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler: Failed executing POST /bulkControlsMapping
     [java] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part
     [java]     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:183) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:?]
     [java]     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:?]
     [java]     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:?]
     [java]     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:?]
     [java]     at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) ~[resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:?]
```

When I test my API with Postman Client, I could see that correct header structure should be like this, but I'm not able to build it manually:

```
POST /bulkControlsMapping HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0af37ee0-9623-43b6-f5f3-bd2c01bdd84c
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bulkMappingFile"; filename="Beta-Test-2.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="countryCode"

MX
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

UPDATE:

I got it to work by using MultiPartFeature,

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MultiPartFeature.class, JacksonFeature.class);
```

and different methods for generating a request using FormDataMultiPart and FormDataContentDisposition.

```
    FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    FormDataContentDisposition.FormDataContentDispositionBuilder builder = FormDataContentDisposition
            .name("controlsBulkMappingFile");
    log.error("FILENAME: " + file.getName());
    builder.fileName(file.getName());
    FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition = builder.build();

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(
                new FormDataBodyPart((file.getName()), fileInputStream,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)
                        .contentDisposition(formDataContentDisposition));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("&&&&&&: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }


    // COUNTRY CODE
    FormDataContentDisposition.FormDataContentDispositionBuilder builder2 = FormDataContentDisposition
            .name("countryCode");
    FormDataContentDisposition formDataContentDisposition2 = builder2.build();
    formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(new FormDataBodyPart("countryCode", countryCode,
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)).contentDisposition(formDataContentDisposition2);

    log.error("MULTIPART: " + formDataMultiPart.getBodyParts().toString());

    Entity<FormDataMultiPart> entity = Entity
            .entity(formDataMultiPart, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

    Response response = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(entity);

    log.error("BULK MAPPING: Response 1: {}", response);

    BulkControlsMappingResponse mappingResponse = response
            .readEntity(BulkControlsMappingResponse.class);
```

My API consumes MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and produces MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON. Now when I use the MultiPartFeature alone, I'm able to send the request but not able to parse the response. I'm getting

```
[tomcat:launchProperties] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
```

Comment: I got it to work by using MultiPartFeature, and different methods for generating a request using FormDataMultiPart and FormDataContentDisposition. 

My API consumes MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA and produces MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON. Now when I use the MultiPartFeature alone, I'm able to send the request but not able to parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by using different features while sending the request, and different for response as follows:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(endPoint).path("bulkControlsMapping")
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```